# Why isn't 'on hover' working?

Tags: html, css

For some reason I can't seem to get on-hover to work:

HTML

```
<div id="custom_nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">•</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">•</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">•</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">•</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">•</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
ul {list-style: none;}    
#custom_nav a:link {text-decoration: none; color:red;} 
#custom_nav a:visited {text-decoration: none; color:red;} 
#custom_nav a:hover {text-decoration: none; color:green;} 
#custom_nav a:active {text-decoration: none; color:blue}
```

Comment: It works for me. Tested with Chrome 32.

Comment: Same, works fine in firefox 27

Comment: @user2898276 you may want to try adding a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [pen](http://codepen.io/) to show us exactly what setup isn't working.

Comment: Also, what browser(s) is it not working in?

Comment: I jut seeing red list bullet on the right hand side of my screen ?

Comment: @HashemQolami so when you hover over any red dot it turns green? I can't understand why  it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Here it is on JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Hr59/ Works for me! Even on IE!

Comment: @Nucleo1985 that's correct but when you hover it should turn to green.

Comment: Your question cannot depend on links to live code that are going to *change* when you fix the problem. If you want to supplement your question with a demonstration, produce a *minimal* example using something like JSFiddle.

Comment: @user2898276 Yes it does. Seems weird.

Comment: Owhh yes, its working fine on my end. Tested on chrome, ff, opera, safari (windows), and IE10.

Comment: @user2898276 Tip: Instead of writing `text-decoration:none;` multiple times just put it under `#custom_nav a {text-decoration:none;}`

Comment: @meagar the live code may be causing the problem. Therefore a Fiddle may not be giving all the info needed to solve the problem.

Comment: Original link http://mrthomason.com/ ***It doesn't work in my IE11 and FF 27.0.1, but it works in chrome 33.0.1750.146m***

Comment: @user2898276 That's exactly why producing a minimal example is important. In doing do, you'll likely figure out exactly what bit of change introduces the bug, and find the answer yourself. If the fiddle doesn't give all the info required to solve the problem, you have *by definition* not produced a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have other elements overlapping those bullets, so they don't receive `:hover`.

If you try removing `.site_header` and all `.project_container` elements, it will work.

To fix it, you can add

```
#custom_nav {
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

in order to make it overlap `.site_header`, which has `z-index:999`

Note there is no point in having so large `z-index` (you have a `z-index:2147483647`!).
You should read [What No One Told You About Z-Index](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/).

Comment: I'm using Cargocollective. The high z index is their doing.